# how compute rolling difference between open year stock price and closing price of that stock with a frequency one Day

Tags: python, pandas

I have stock data for over 30 years . what am trying to do is calculate whether the stock rose or fell during an year using **`rolling_apply()`**.

The frequency is one day an the window is 252 with **`min_period`** of 2 days.

Due to the massive amount of data am trying to avoid a for loop since it greatly slows the execution and pandas seems to be the best bet.

Here an image of the sample data.

[the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMjgu.png)[image]
what I want to achieve is for example after entering the date e.g 2015-12-22, the rolling function should compute whether through the year starting from 2015-12-22 to 2014-12-22 the value `open_price`( at 2015-12-2 ) - `close_price`( 2014-12-22 ) increased or reduced and return the value then from 2014-12-22 to 2013-12-22 all the way to 1997. Then do the same for 2015-12-23, all the way to 2015-12-31.

**The value returned should be the number of years the stock had risen.** For example given for the first date e.g 2015-12-22 the opening price was at **`663.xx`** and at 2014-12-22 the closing price was **`660.00`**, the stock had risen hence increment a counter. Then if the stock had risen from 2014-12-22 to 2013-12-22 it should increment the counter until the last year in the data is reached, i.e. if there were 30 yrs and it rose for 14 value returned is 14 for that date then it should roll to the other dates and do the same.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np

Data = pd.io.parsers.read_csv( "amzn.csv" ) # Reading data from the csv

def append_date( Data ):                    # Appending year mont and day column
    data = Data
    data['date'] = pd.to_datetime( data.Date )
    data['year'], data['month'], data['day'] = data['date'].dt.year, \
                                               data['date'].dt.month, \
                                               data['date'].dt.day
    num_of_yrs   = np.size( np.where( ( np.unique( data['year'].values ))))
    data.ix[:,0] = pd.to_datetime( data.ix[:,0] )
    del data['date']
    return data, num_of_yrs

Data_datetime, num_of_years= a ppend_date( Data )

        Date        Open        High         Low       Close   Volume  \
     0 2015-12-23  666.500000  666.599976  656.630005  663.700012  2714900   
     1 2015-12-22  666.830017  668.489990  659.260010  663.150024  2664000   
     2 2015-12-21  668.500000  669.900024  658.929993  664.510010  3197500   
     3 2015-12-18  668.650024  676.840027  664.130005  664.140015  6765900   
     4 2015-12-17  680.000000  682.500000  670.650024  670.650024  3663500   

   Adj Close  year  month  day  
0  663.700012  2015     12   23  
1  663.150024  2015     12   22  
2  664.510010  2015     12   21  
3  664.140015  2015     12   18  
4  670.650024  2015     12   17
```

Comment: Could you post your dataframe to work with instead of pic?

Comment: just added the code to show how i obtained the data

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking to do?

```
import pandas as pd

def up_over_period(s):
    """Check if most recent value in Series is greater than the earliest.
    """
    return s[0] > s[-1]

#Reading data from the csv
df = pd.read_csv("amzn.csv")

period = 253

df['UpOnYear'] = pd.rolling_apply(
    df['Close'], 
    window=period, 
    func=up_over_period, 
    )
```

**Edited in response to comment**

```
s = pd.rolling_apply(
    df['Close'], 
    window=period, 
    func=up_over_period, 
    ).shift(-period + 1)[::-1]

s = (s.groupby((s != s.shift()).cumsum()).cumsum() / (period - 1)).apply(math.ceil)

df['ConsecPeriodsUp'] = s
```

Comment: Thanks but not quite the answer. The value returned should be the number of years the stock had risen .for example given for the first date e.g 2015-12-22 the opening price was at 663.xx and at 2014-12-22 the closing price was 660 the stock had risen hence increment a counter. then if the stock had risen from 2014-12-22 to 2013-12-22 it should increment the counter until the last year in the data is reached. i.e if there were 30 yrs and it rose for 14 value returned is 14 for that date then it should roll to the other dates and do the same.

Comment: Maybe say that in the question then.